# Android app to automatically send incoming SMS messages to a URL

Tags: android, automation, sms, url

I'm looking for an Android app that can automatically forward any incoming SMS (text) messages to a custom URL.

So basically this:
[image: auto forward sms to url]

When searching around I find lots of forwarding apps that can send SMS messages to another phone, or to email, or to Telegram, etc. But I like to just send it (preferably through a POST request) to a custom URL. So I can further process it there however I want.

Any recommendations?

Paid solutions also fine (as long as it's one time payment, no concurrent subscriptions).

Comment: [SMSSync](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/org.addhen.smssync) sounds like it would fit the bill, but it's no longer maintained. And it comes with several trackers (Firebase, Google Analytics). "It supports filtering text messages by keywords and can transmit the text message to a configured callback URL via HTTP POST request" – which sounds like a match to your requirements. If it's acceptable let me know and I make it an answer.

Comment: Or possibly [If This, Then That](https://ifttt.com/), where you might have to code  a script to send the POST message ? Have a look at some existing [recipes](https://ifttt.com/recipes)

Comment: @Izzy the SMSSync doesn't seem to work anymore (also, it feels quite risky running a .apk installed from a random website, rather than the play store, it's something I'd really not prefer to run continuously)

Comment: @Mawg Thanks, yes that seems hopeful. Is there a way to look how existing recipes are built? Or is there any guidelines on how I could make my own recipe, which is triggered on incoming SMS messages and then performs some action (such as POST'ing to some custom URL) ?

Comment: Looks like you have to sign up now. If/when you do, I am sure that the docs will explain all. Receipt of an SMS seems like a common enough `if` trigger

Comment: @RocketNuts sad to read (if someone can confirm and name the Android version(s) tried, I'll take it off). And that "random website" is my own F-Droid repo – plus you can see what libraries each app ships with and how Virustotal rates it (which of course is no guarantee). I'd rather avoid Playstore instead as it doesn't even tell that, and has lots of "spyware" ;) In fact, my Android phones run completely without GApps, and I use F-Droid instead. // Other automation tools (MacroDroid, Tasker) certainly can achieve the task, too.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, hold that, I was too early! I must have done something wrong. Got SmsSync working now! Just one thing, I added 'Update custom web service' to call my own URL upon receiving SMS messages. The URL is 100% working correctly. However when I click 'Test integration' it says "web service doesn't seem to have the right endpoint". However on the server end I can see the call was actually made correctly, including all post parameters! Is there a specific kind of response I have to return?

Comment: @RocketNuts no idea, I'm not an Android programmer.

Comment: I have this implemented by sending *two* email messages in the first place: one notification sends email to an SMS-gateway, and a second notification sends an email to my regular email server (where a filter or script could trigger some action upon mail arrival.)

Comment: @knb By sending to an SMS-gateway, I think you mean sending a message (e.g. an email in this case) to a phone number as SMS. But I actually meant the other way around: whenever someone sends *me* an SMS message, I want my phone to automatically forward that to a URL (or to an email or otherwise, but preferably just a URL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was needed the same functions so I created a simple SMS to URL Android forwarding [App](https://github.com/bogkonstantin/android_income_sms_gateway_webhook).
Since Google refused to publish it in the Play Store, because it needed read SMS permission, you can install it directly from the apk [here](https://github.com/bogkonstantin/android_income_sms_gateway_webhook/releases).
If you miss some functions in this app - feel free to open a ticket on [Github](https://github.com/bogkonstantin/android_income_sms_gateway_webhook/issues).

Comment: That looks awesome man! I'm actually about to switch to a new Android phone, will install your app and let you know if I have any feedback 

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use this paid solution (7$ one time)

https://www.forward-sms-to-rest-api.com/forward_sms_to_rest_api.php

Comment: How are you affiliated with it

Answer (score 0):

There is this open source app that does exactly what you are requesting:
https://f-droid.org/de/packages/tech.bogomolov.incomingsmsgateway/

Comment: How are you affiliated with it.

Comment: How is this different to the one posted 2 years ago

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65832)